# Can I reach a container by it's hostname from another container running on another node in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, networking, kubernetes, kubespray

I believe my question is pretty straightforward. I'm doing my prerequisites to install Kubernetes cluster on bare metal.

Let's say I have:

**master** - hostname for Docker DB container which is fixed on first node

**slave** - hostname for Docker DB container which is fixed on second node

Can I communicate with **master** from any container (app, etc.) in a cluster regardless it's running on the same node or not?

Is this a default behaviour?
Or anything additional should be done?

I assume that  I need to setup `hostname` parameter in YAML or JSON file so Kubernetes is aware what the hostname is.

Probably this is not the factor, but I plan to use Kubespray installation method so it gets Calico networking for k8s.

Many thanks

Comment: The Kubernetes [Connecting Applications with Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/) documentation is probably relevant.

Comment: Thanks, this why I wasn't 100% sure whether it's straightforward. From documentation: "By default, Docker uses host-private networking, so containers can talk to other containers only if they are on the same machine" - Kubernetes solves that issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,

You can access and communication from any container in a `namespace` via hostname.

Here is an example about Kubernetes `Service` configure:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: master
  labels:
    name: master
  namespace: smart-office
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5672
    name: master
    targetPort: 5672
  selector:
    name: master
```

`Deployment` configure:

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: master
  labels:
    name: master
  namespace: smart-office
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: master
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/scrape: "false"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: master
        image: rabbitmq:3.6.8-management
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5672
          name: master
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
```

And from other services, for e.g your `slaver` `.env` will be:

```
AMQP_HOST=master <---- The hostname
AMQP_PORT=5672
AMQP_USERNAME=guest
AMQP_PASSWORD=guest
AMQP_HEARTBEAT=60
```

It's will work inside Cluster even if you not publish External IP.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Great, thanks. This confirms that networking is easy bit just by specifying names/hostnames in YAML for deployment. I plan to use a separate namespace so it's also useful that containers can communicate in the same namespace only.

Comment: You have 'master' as the name for the service, for the deployment and for the container. Which of them is actually used for routing to the destination? 
Is it done based on the container name? e.g. if there are multiple containers in the deployment, they would not all have the same name as the deployment.