# Expose services locally

Tags: kubernetes

There're some ways to expose services: NodePort, LoadBalancer, etc

K8s cluster is in-network 192.168.10.0/24 but I want to access it from 10.100.10.0/24, assume that we have a firewall configured.

How can I access services in the k8s cluster from an external local network 10.100.10.0/24?

Comment: I guess you already answered your question: NodePort, Load Balancer. Or what to do you want to know?

Comment: @Tuyen Pham: I guess your answer at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677937/can-i-reach-a-container-by-its-hostname-from-another-container-running-on-anoth/55678129#55678129
Access via service hostname.

Comment: NodePort consumes ports on nodes, LoadBalancer requires public ip address that supports from "provider"?. externalName requires a valid CNAME.
How to specify ip address 10.100.10.21/32 for example for service in k8s cluster with LoadBalancer type? and how to use `mylocaldomain.local` as domain name for externalName type?

Answer (score 3):

You've already mentioned it [`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) and [`LoadBalancer`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer).

In the case of `NodePort`, you would use the IP address of the node and the specific TCP/UDP port on that node.

In the case of `LoadBalancer`, you would you use an ['internal'](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#internal-load-balancer) load balancer and use the IP or DNS entry for that load balancer.